# Time Complexity of Leetcode 387

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to have a better understanding of time complexity, this particular example seems to be confusing me.

Problem: (Source LeetCode)
Given a string, find the first non-repeating character in it and return it's index. If it doesn't exist, return -1.

**Examples:**

```
s = "leetcode"
return 0.

s = "loveleetcode",
return 2.
```

Note: You may assume the string contain only lowercase letters.

Based on my solution, i know that the for loop will iterate through the string worse case O(n) time, n being the length of the string. However inside the for loop im checking the count of each character and i know the count() method itself requires O(n) time. So making this a O(n^2) solution? Do i have that logic correct?

## My Solution:

```py
class Solution:
    def firstUniqChar(self, s: str) -> int:
       
        if len(s) == 0:
            return -1
        for char in range(len(s)):
            if s.count(s[char]) > 1:
                pass
            else: 
                return(char)
        return(-1)
```

So my code works for smaller test cases, however when testing a case where s is a huge string, it says time limit exceeded. I do not need solutions for the problem rather i just want to know if O(n^2) is the actual time complexity for my code.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. In practice you have two nested loops, each counting to `n` in the worst case, hence `n^2`.

Comment: If `len(set(s)) == 0`, then `len(s) == 0` as well. Also, your implementation is O(n^2), but it doesn't have to be. You can do this in O(n) time if you are willing to use O(n) additional space.

Comment: @chepner You don't even need `O(n)` space. You only need to remember the previous character.

Comment: Extra space needed is only **O(26)** :-), a list to hold the status of each letter.  For instance, the final state for "abba cd dice" could be `[-1, -1, -1, -1, 11, 0, 0, 0, 9, ...]`.

Comment: @Selcuk, still O(N) space because you may only find a non duplicate at the end of the string

Comment: @smac89 Ah, I misread the question. But it can still be constant as Prune pointed out.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the clarification, btw i was able to write the code in O(n) time using a hash table.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is correct.  The complexity of `for ... len(s)` is `O(|s|)`, and so is `s.count`.  Since you nested them, then you have `O(|s|^2)`